# net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: Object 'my_table_name' does not exist or not authorized

Tags: java, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Spring boot application with Snowflake driver to fetch data from snowflake database and display in front end application. I am using JdbcTemplate of springframework to query and map result to POJO with the help of RowMapper.
This works fine if I use snowflake-jdbc driver version of 3.6.8 or 3.7.2 but don't work for the same code base if I change driver version to 3.8.x/3.9.x/3.10.x/3.12.x/3.13.24

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
            <artifactId>snowflake-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.24</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:snowflake://<accountname>.snowflakecomputing.com:443/?CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE=true&user=xxx&password=xxx&warehouse=xxx&role=xxx&db=xxx&schema=xxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.example.demo.SnowflakeDialect
```

DAO : here pojo class contains only one field with getter setter

```
//exception on below line
List<my_pojo_class> data=jdbcTemplate.query("select column1 FROM  my_table_name LIMIT 2",
            new RowMapper<my_pojo_class>(){  
                @Override  
                public my_pojo_class mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {  
                my_pojo_class layer = new my_pojo_class();
                layer.setColumn1(rs.getString(1));
                return layer; 
            }  
            });
```

Please guide me where i am going wrong here

Tried to create connection as mentioned in Snowflake document https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html , it works but not sure why i cant use jdbc template

```
 String url = "jdbc:snowflake://<account_identifier>.snowflakecomputing.com";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("user", "<user>");
    prop.put("password", "<password>");
    prop.put("db", "<database_name>");
    prop.put("schema", "<schema_name>");
    prop.put("warehouse", "<warehouse_name>");
    prop.put("role", "<role_name>");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);
```

Comment: Tried to create connection as mentioned in Snowflake document , it works but not sure why i cant use jdbc template

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you probably have no access to the my_table_name table or the table does exist.

1. Check the history page and find the failed query. Verify the role name, database name and schema are correct.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html

2. Try to run the same query through UI. Make sure you use the same role.

Comment: Table does exist and query is working fine with same role etc since With the same code base by just changing the dependency of snowflake driver to 3.6.8 it is working.

Comment: What do you see in the query history? Do they see any difference? I suspect that the  schema/db or role properties are not passed correct (maybe because of driver version)?

Comment: Query shows up in history table only if I run by using 3.6.8 version else query doesn't not populate in History.

Comment: I posted application.properties as well. I used the same configuration of key value pair. Is there any change in syntax  to be used for higher version?

Comment: The error message you shared (SQL compilation error: Object 'my_table_name' does not exist or not authorized) comes from Snowflake. So the query should be visible in the query history.

Comment: If in your history, you can see only the queries from 3.6.8, I can assume that in 3.8.x connection, the role/user configuration is different/or not applied. Are you able to use the accountadmin role in your UI and check if you see the problematic queries? If yes, than you should be see what role and other session parameters were applied with 3.8 and above.

Comment: yes, i am using admin role only in my configuration and UI. I tried one more approach (added in my question at last section) where if  i am not using springframework provided jdbctemplate and instead creating my own connection to execute query works fine.